# How to get INPUT field data in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am tried to using following syntaxes but, I didn't get result.

```
package demo_package;
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.testng.Assert; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Class {
public WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(); 

@BeforeTest
public void beforetest() {
driver.get("URL");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
}

@Test
public void Login() {
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
}

@Test
public void Gettext() {
driver.findElement(By.id("psge_click")).click();      
WebElement msg=driver.findElement(By.id("input_id"));     
String expectedText=("sample text");     
String text=msg.getText();    
System.out.println(text);    
Assert.assertEquals(text,expectedText);
}
```

I am using this code for ERROR Message, getting result, but input data not getting "empty" is displayed

Comment: Is this the full code? Where you are creating web driver object. Ex `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()`

Comment: I am updating my full code. Please once check

Comment: Is there any test suite for your test classes? When gettext() test method is invoked, Are you sure your application is logged in?

Comment: Yes,I am logged in successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below to get the data from `input` field :-

```
WebElement msg=driver.findElement(By.id("input_id"));
String text = msg.getAttribute("value");
```

Hope it will help you....:)

Comment: It's Working Thank You